# Why did $Ext$ appear to make the sequence exact after taking its dual?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The above question is about the exact sequence in the bottom of the following figure from p196 of Hatcher's text. After taking the dual of the original short exact sequence, $Ext$ comes in at the end to make the new sequence exact. I need justification for this step, but I couldn't find in the text.

[image]

Comment: Ext is the derived functor of Hom. This means precisely that Hom turns short exact sequences into long exact sequences involving Ext. This is a truncation of that long exact sequence coming from the fact that $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}, G)$ vanishes.

Comment: From your mention of the long exact sequence, I found an explicit formula of the relevant long exact sequence! Thanks so much.